# Ruby on Rails - Form Field update value upon key press using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

How can I update a RoR field in the front end using JS? I have the following code below however this does not update the values I get.

**_form.html.erb**

```
       <div class="form-group row col-md-6">
         <label for="example-email-input" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">Hours Worked</label>
          <div class="col-sm-7">
        <%= form.text_field :hours_worked, :class=>"form-control",:type=>"number", :name=>"hworked"%>
           </div>
       </div>
        <div class="form-group row col-md-6">
                <label for="example-search-input" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">
                    *Base Pay
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <!--<%base_rate=@attendance.employee.basic_rate%>
                     <%basic_pay=base_rate*@attendance.days_worked%>-->
             <%= form.text_field :base_pay, :class=>"form-control",:type=>"number",:name=>"basepay"%>
             </div>
       </div>
```

JS on same page

```
 <script>
        $(':input').bind('keypress keydown keyup change',function(){
            <%base_rate=@attendance.employee.basic_rate%>

                //var Calc_basepay = $('#basepay');
                var hours_worked = $(':input[name="hworked"]').val();
                //var hours_worked = $('#hworked');
                //var hworked = hours_worked.val();

                var basepay= hours_worked*<%=base_rate%>;



                //Calc_basepay.val(basepay);
                $(':input[name="basepay"]').val(basepay);

        });
  </script>
```

[image]

**Screenshot of inspect element**

I am able to get the value "1.0" which is the basic rate from the db and it looks like it's being inserted correctly into the Javascript.

[image]

Did I miss anything? Not sure why it's not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Using the onKeyUp worked. I called a function o() which updated the dependent field.

Ruby

```
<%= form.text_field :hours_worked, :class=>"form-control",:type=>"number", :name=>"hworked", :onKeyUp=>"o()",:id=>"attendance_hours_worked"%>
```

JS

```
function o(){

document.getElementById("attendance_base_pay").value=document.getElementById("attendance_hours_worked").value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, adding to @Acrux's Answer. You should also avoid using JS, use JQuery. Avoid using `document.getElementById`, you can easily do this in JQuery by `$('<id>').value`.